# How to get the datetime from NumberLong

Tags: java, json

I received a JSON field from mondb:

```
"publishDate": NumberLong("1500948351000"),
```

I try to parse it as this in Java:

```
String docTime = new DateTime(jsonDoc.getLong(publishDate)).toString();
```

But receive an exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["publishDate"] is not a long.
```

How to retrieve the datetime from the NumberLong?

Comment: How does it relate to IntelliJ ?

Comment: Maybe am dumb, but I never seen JSON format like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'NumberLong("1500948351000")' is not a long.

```
String aa = jsonDoc.getString(publishDate)
```

is probably the String with value NumberLong("1500948351000"). And then you can use

```
String longString = aa.subString(aa.indexOf("\"") + 1, aa.lastIndexOf("\""));
long pbDate = Long.parseLong(longString);
```

to obtain the long value.